# Teamcity rerun step with pending changes

Tags: teamcity

We have a build chain setup using teamcity 2017.2.

It looks like the following

A -> B

A:

- generates a version number using gitversion
- has a VCS root defined
- uses gitversion command line to define a version number

B:

- sets its version number to the same as A using a dependency proprty
- has a snapshot dependency on A with the following settings

  - Do not run new build if there is a suitable one
  - Only use successful builds from suitable ones
  - On failed dependency: cancel build
  - On failed to start/canceled dependency: make build failed to start

When I make a commit and run B it will trigger A and then B will run, teamcity will show the pending change of the commit that I just made.

However if B fails for whatever reason (and A succeeds) when I rerun B it will rerun for the same commit but the pending changes will be empty. The same also happens if I just want to rerun a previous successful build of B.

The reason this matters is that I'm using the teamcity api to pull a list of changes for a build and passing that off to my deployment tool.

I've tried enabling "Show changes for snapshot dependencies in B" but that did not seem to have an effect

Comment: I have exactly the same problem! Had to double check the author to see if I asked it while moonwalking . Did you have any progress with this?

Comment: Unfortunately not :( , its more a nice to have in our implmentation so we can survive without it